# $A,B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. $A = A^*$. Is $B = B^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Title says it all really.

$A = PD_AP^{-1}$, $B  = PD_{B}P^{-1}$. We know $A = A^*$. Can we say for sure that $B = B^*$?

Comment: If $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues and $B$ has real eigenvalues, then we can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Suppose that $A=\operatorname{Id}$ and that $B$ is diagonalizable, but $B\neq B^*$. Then $A$ and $B$ are obviously simultaneously diagonalizable, $A=A^*$, and $B\neq B^*$.